# how to export #hashtag twitter feed to a local file?

Tags: twitter, rss, sentiment-analysis

I am working on sentiment analysis for BREXIT on twitter. I have got myself a #Brexit twitter feed url for myself
which looks like this:

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwP3em_xpan6NxsO17UU6R7dLATF3WJbGgf6XCW-OPte2gpHTY/exec?761487686360297472
```

and its working...

I want to pipe the feed to a local .txt or .tsv file.
I will also be satisfied if its exported to .xlsx file or Google Doc.

Purpose is to have huge dataset of tweets for sentiment analysis.

Please comment if anything additional information about the project is needed before down-voting the question

Answer (score -1):

Chuck it!!
I figured it out... Here you go...

Make a twitter account.

Follow the instructions properly from [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feed/28149/)

Then go [here](https://ifttt.com/recipes/89246-save-all-tweets-with-any-hashtag-to-google-docs-spreadsheet)

```
Paste the feed url you created there without any further change
```

give a file name to the spreadsheet that will appear on Drive

Then add the recipe.

wait for few minutes and TaDa!!!...

- I manually made a IFTTT folder in my drive.. Do this if it takes too
  long